# Make markdown respect a double newline as end of list formatting

Tags: feature-request, markdown, indentation

I was writing a question in which I used a list to indicate the steps my code takes, immediately followed by the code. Like this:

- Foo the bar
- bar the foo

  Foo = bar / 12
  bar = 6 / Foo

Albeit being properly indented with four spaces and two newlines inbetween the list and the code this doesn't work. As a work around I can add a `<br>` tag in between like this:

- Foo the bar
- bar the foo

```
Foo = bar / 12
bar = 6 / Foo
```

But this requires three blank lines between the list and the codeblock. Can we please make markdown respect two new lines as being the end of the list?

ps. I know there are a lot of bug reports about this, but this is a feature-request.

Comment: Use the best text editor in the world: `:se ts=4`, Enter, `V3j>`

Comment: The posted example uses a triple-newline, which actually makes more sense to end a list (double-newline and indent looks more like a new paragraph within a list item, which is also how it's currently parsed).

Answer (score 8):

Treating a double newline specially is not how Markdown works.

To terminate a list or other indented Markdown content, you can use an empty comment instead. For example:

```
 -  foo
 -  bar

<!-- -->

    code { block }
```

which renders as:

- foo
- bar

```
code { block }
```

Comment: I know that it's not how it works, hence the [feature-request] as IMO it **should** work like that.

Answer (score 5):

Use fences rather than indenting code blocks:

````
- Foo the bar
- bar the foo

```
Foo = bar / 12 bar = 6 / Foo
```
````

> - Foo the bar
> - bar the foo
>
> `Foo = bar / 12 bar = 6 / Foo`

Comment: That certainly can be an option, but if I copy already indented code it becomes a horrible mess of double indention.

Comment: The **`{}`** editor button (or Ctrl+K) can also un-indent selected blocks if each line is already consistently indented with 4 spaces. @Luuklag